# Prevent repetition in directive attributes?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive which adds an input inside a bootstrap `form-group` / `form-control`

It watches the field's `$valid` and `$invalid` values, and sets appropriate bootstrap error/valid css classes.

This is the markup:

```
<fe-input ng-model='user.first_name' field='first_name' submitted='submitted' label='First Name'></fe-input>
<fe-input ng-model='user.last_name'  field='last_name'  submitted='submitted' label='Last Name'></fe-input>
<fe-input ng-model='user.phone'      field='phone'      submitted='submitted' label='Phone'></fe-input>
```

It relies on a scope variable `submitted` being set when the user attempts to submit the form (so we don't show invalid fields before the user has done anything)

You can see there is a **lot of repetition**.

- `field` = `model.field` : the field name is always the same as the model field name
- `submitted='submitted'` : repeated every time

**Ideally I'd like to cut it down to this:**

```
<fe-input ng-model='user.first_name' label='First Name'></fe-input>
<fe-input ng-model='user.last_name'  label='Last Name'></fe-input>
<fe-input ng-model='user.phone'      label='Phone'></fe-input>
```

It would enforce:

- form field's name is always the same as model's field name
- `submitted` on the parent scope is implicitly required

### Questions:

- Is this even possible?
- If so, any suggestions on how to achieve this?

### Plunker:

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IQsvUypeOPOKrMzrqXdC?p=preview) showing what I've currently got.

### Directive source code:

This is my directive's html template:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success': submitted && isValid,
                                    'has-error'  : submitted && isInvalid }">
    <label class="control-label" for="{{ field }}">
        {{ label }}
    </label>
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           ng-model="model"
           name="{{ field }}"
           id="{{ field }}"
           required>
</div>
```

and the directive source:

```
angular.module('directive.form-elements', []).directive('feInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['^form'],
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel',
            label: '@',
            field: '@',
            submitted: '='  // feedback only when the form has been submitted
        },
        templateUrl: 'components/form-elements/input.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$parent.$watch('form.'+scope.field+'.$valid', function(isValid) {
                scope.isValid = isValid;
            });
            scope.$parent.$watch('form.'+scope.field+'.$invalid', function(isInvalid) {
                scope.isInvalid = isInvalid;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**submitted:**

`submitted` is a variable in the form controller's scope, and is shared by all the input elements in the form. It exists solely to enable the valid/invalid styling only when the user has actually attempted to submit the form

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('UserCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.submitted = false;

    $scope.submit = function(form) {
        $scope.submitted = true;
        if (!form.$valid)
            return;
        // do submit
    });
```

Comment: Is submitted used somewhere else too? And how is it set?

Comment: It is in the form controller's scope, and is set in the `submit` action. The idea is that all `form-elements` use the same `submitted`. When the form is submitted, `submitted` is set to true, and consequently all `form-group`s which have `$valid=true` will have `class="has-success"` and those with `$invalid=true` will have `class="has-error"`. Submitted exists in the parent's scope (ie: the form's scope) purely for turning on the valid/invalid css styling

Comment: You extremely over-complicated a small issue, could you please produce a plunker? My notes on the current version  of your code: TRY **NEVER** TO USE `$parent`, can't see why `ng-model` and field both necessary if they are using the same thing, you haven't use`$pristine` and `$dirty`, why?

Comment: @Linial `$dirty` is not the same as `submitted` - `$dirty` is when something/anything has been entered. Showing a user there is an error when they've entered the first letter of their email address is not a good user experience IMO. `field` is the field on the form. `ng-model` is the value on the model. They are not the same I believe. How would you do what I've done w/o using `$parent`?

Comment: @SteveLorimer Hi, on this issue, it would be easier to debug with plunker to find a solution without using $parent. Basically, using $parent is taking a big assumption on the state of the parent scope, which is working now, but could make troubles in the future. please add a plunkr and I'd be happy to see how we could use different pattern than $parent, and also make your directive much shorter.

Comment: @Linial - I see what you're saying. Please forgive the fact that I'm no expert on the matter! [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IQsvUypeOPOKrMzrqXdC?p=preview) added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to create a parent directive that handles the repetitive stuff. The HTML could look something like this:

```
<form name="userForm" fe-form="user">
  <fe-input field='first_name' label='First Name'></fe-input>
  <fe-input field='last_name'  label='Last Name'></fe-input>
  <fe-input field='phone'      label='Phone'></fe-input>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
<form>
```

The parent directive:

```
angular.module('directive.form-elements', []).directive('feForm', function() {
return {
    controller: function($scope, attrs) {
      var formName = $attrs.name;
      var submitted = false;

      this.hasSuccess = function(field) {
        return submitted && $scope[formName][field].$valid;
      };

      this.hasError = function(field) {
        return submitted && $scope[formName][field].$invalid;
      };

      this.setSubmitted = function(value) {
        submitted = value;
      }
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      controller.model = $scope[$attrs.feForm];
      element.on('submit', function(event) {
          controller.setSubmitted(true);
```

The important thing is that it has a controller that can be used by your other directive. We also encapsulate the error and success state.

Your original directive:

```
angular.module('directive.form-elements', []).directive('feInput', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: ['^form', '^feForm'],
    scope: {
        field: '@',
        label: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: 'components/form-elements/input.html',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
        var feFormController = controllers[1];

        scope.model = feFormController.model;
        scope.hasSuccess = feFormController.hasSuccess;
        scope.hasError = feFormController.hasError;
    }
};
});
```

Here we can use the controller of the parent directive.

Small modifications of your template:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-success':  hasSuccess(field),
                                'has-error'  : hasError(field) }">
<label class="control-label" for="{{ field }}">
    {{ label }}
</label>
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       ng-model="model[field]"
       name="{{ field }}"
       id="{{ field }}"
       required>
</div>
```

Please understand that while this code may work for you, it's rather meant as illustration, or a starting point if you will.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I have implemented what you've suggested ([plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CjN7mZjJckrYuvyGFN1T?p=preview)). The parent controller's `$scope.model` ("userCtrl") does not link to the `fe-form` directive controller's scope. Do you know why? TIA!

Comment: @SteveLorimer That's what I meant by starting point ;) You could use a watcher for that use case, but I decided to follow your example and established a direct binding `<fe-input model='user.first_name'` and derived the field name. [see updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jJyyMS6eeAUycGa6jdEA?p=preview). Btw: Never use `ng-model` as attribute if you don't need the `ngModel` directive.